How can I temporary comment out a line in Python code when it is in middle of multi-lines ends with a "\"?
When debuging with Python, what brings me difficulties is that I want temporary comment out a line and run the code, but it is in middle of multi-lines ends with a "", then I can not do this directly, for example:
A.func1() \
 .func2() \
 .func3() \
 .func4()

since
A.func1() \
 # .func2() \
 .func3() \
 .func4()

cause errors, is there any convenient methods to do this? Thanks in advance.
Tried single line comment, multi line comment, can not do this.
